# How to find matches in regex only if they are between particular strings?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find multiple matches in a specific position in text.

For example, in the following text, I want to find all `a=.*;` between `abcd` and `xyz`

```
abcd
a=1;
some text
a=2; some text
b=3;
a=4;
xyz
a=5;
a=6;
```

So it should only match:

```
 a=1;   
 a=2;
 a=4;
```

and don't match:

```
a=5;
a=6;
```

So far I tried the following regex:

```
(?<=abcd\n)(.*)(?=\nxyz)
```

which returns the string between `'abcd'` and `'xyz'` ,but I don't succeed to match all `a=.*;` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<=abcd[\s\S]*)a=.*;(?=[\s\S]*xyz)
```

See [JS regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/SjUECv/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abcd                     'abcd'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  a=                       'a='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    xyz                      'xyz'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```